# Keeping a series of messages in an MQTT Topic

Tags: queue, store, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. If I set a number of messages to be persisted under a topic for some period of time, can I later grab all of them?

I have an MQTT Broker (Mosquitto) set up already for communication between my services but I now also need some storage for several messages, ideally keeping the last 24 hours worth of messages and being able to pull them out later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message persistence is only for clients that have subscribed but are currently disconnected and when they do reconnect do so with the `cleanSession` flag set to false. In which case all the messages published while that client was disconnected.

You can not use a MQTT broker to store an arbitrary number of messages and retrieve them later. If a client is connected then all messages for it's collection of subscribed topics will be delivered as soon as possible.

If you want to log messages for later you will have to implement this separately, there are plenty of examples of applications that store messages in databases available

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that was the case but thought I'd double check since I've already got it there

Comment: Am I right in understanding that if two consecutive messages are published to the broker on the same topic, then the second _replaces_ the first – the broker only retains the second. If the subscriber you described is connected, will they receive both messages? If they were disconnected and reconnect will they only receive the most recent of the two messages?

Comment: The broker will always send the last message with a retained bit set, but will also send **all** queued messages as described above, so it will receive both messages (not necessarily in order, as the retained messages may be sent first)

Comment: Thanks, what if a message is retained but a subscriber never reconnects? The message would be retained forever and orphaned messages would pile up. I haven't been able to find an MQTT standard for how to purge these, is it up to the broker implementation and based on memory constraints?

Comment: Retained messages are stored once per topic, not per client (and delivered every time a client subscribes to the topic irrespective of QOS). How long queued messages are kept is broker dependant